# How to Create Columns with Dynamic Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

How can I organize the css so that every iteration of `<%= averaged.name %>(<%= averaged.metric %>)` is a new column?

averaged.name (averaged.metric) has many results. Each result has its own row in its respective column.

EX:

```
NAME(METRIC) | NAME(METRIC) | NAME(METRIC) etc...
RESULT       | RESULT       | RESULT      
RESULT       | RESULT       | RESULT    
RESULT       | RESULT       | RESULT
etc...
```

With this code I'm able to get the result rows, but not the name (metric) columns. The latter shows up as news rows too going down the page instead of across it.

```html
<table>
  <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
    <% if averaged.user == current_user %>      
      <th><%= averaged.name %>(<%= averaged.metric %>)</th>
     <% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
      <tr><td><%= result.result_value %></td></tr>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %> 
</table>
```

**quantifieds.css.scss**

```html
select {
  width: 30.1%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.america {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 1.2em;
  padding-right: 1.2em;
}

.america2 {
  padding-top: .7em;
}

.america3 {
  float: right;
}

.btn-group {
  background: #c0392b;
  border: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.deadline {
  width: 8%
}

.goal {
  width: 70%
}

td {
  padding-top: .7em;
  padding-bottom: .7em;
  padding-left: .7em;
  padding-right: .7em;
}

.btn {
  background: #c0392b;
  border: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:active{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.values-button {
  margin-top : -9px;
  margin-left : 10px; 
}
```

```html
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);

$body-bg:                         #ecf0f1;
$font-family-sans-serif:          'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$navbar-height:                   45px;
$navbar-default-bg:               white;
$navbar-default-brand-color:      #c0392b;
$brand-primary:                   #000;
$jumbotron-bg:                    #FFFFFF;

@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';

.center {
     text-align: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
     font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  &:hover {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help! I had a hard time understanding how to format css/html tables with the dynamism of Ruby on Rails so if you any great resources that could help me learn I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks again!

Comment: It's unclear what kind of result you expect.  Your example output looks like something that you're describing that you do not want.  You say you want multiple columns, but how many? How many `result`'s do you expect to output? Is that a variable number? You might want to use example data in your output.  Without showing CSS and Bootstrap in your example code, there's no way to understand if CSS and Bootstrap is changing your layout.  Your problem has more to do with the HTML table output than CSS/Bootstrap.

Comment: @sealocal User's can create multiple results. To clarify their is the result model, which consists of name, metric, & result_value. EX ran (miles) 1.2, 2, 6. The `results` are a variable number depending on what the User submits and within the `results` form a User can have many `result_values`. I'd say 5 `results` on one line is the most I'd want in order to avoid the `results` from running off the page. To clarify the name (metric)'s would run horizontal and `result_value` run down the page.

Comment: @sealocal I've been playing around with bootstrap <div>'s but still with no luck in solving this problem. I added the bootstrap assets in the above question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem, but from what I can tell your code prints one `th` element, then multiple `tr` elements, each one holding a value.  Your code looks like it should return the expected table you're asking for.  If you want to apply CSS (or Bootstrap) to your table, then you have to assign `class` and `id` attributes to your HTML tags.  You have not shown those, so it seems that Bootstrap should not have any effect on your code.  Your code does not show a `div` that you mention. I'd suggest pasting the HTLM output of your table if you want further engagement from others.

Comment: As a side, since you asked for learning resources, Code School has good video content, with a recently launched Bootsrap course.  They're showing a discount subscription here: http://mbsy.co/CodeSchool/12141376?url=https://www.codeschool.com/enrollments/dC90a2Q1T1FTRFpHWmpuMFJHYnIwWURxeWg3WE0wY0dsb1FtZnh5U3pUUT0tLWhDN2ttVS9ZOEFBVk8yRHpRYlFrbHc9PQ==

Answer (score 0):

For a start, a basic HTML table looks like this:

```html
<table>
  <th colspan="1">Ran (miles)</th>
  <tr>
    <td>1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```